# Ex Employee as Consultant

Tags: audit

We are in process of going for SOC2 audit. I need your help in clarifying an HR element. The problem statement(s) is as below

1. If we want to hire ex-employee of a company as a consultant what all criteria shall be followed e.g. background checks, data sharing, assets etc.
2. Can the person who was ex-employee turning consultant be given a company email? Or can he use his own? And if the latter, then how to ensure the security of data in that case?

Looking for valuable suggestions.

Comment: This is something to ask your assessor. Being an ex-employee doesn't matter at all. Follow the basic guidelines for any consultant.

Comment: Sure Schroeder. Since we don't have any fix guidelines around this I thought checking here.

Comment: Have you checked the SOC 2 guidelines? The points of focus have things to say about HR practices like this.

Answer (score 1):

What do your documented processes say you do?

If your processes and controls say that everyone joining the organization undergoes a background check, then the employee-turned-consultant should undergo a background check prior to onboarding. If you say that all business must be conducted using company-managed email addresses, then you need to issue your consultants company-managed email addresses.

On the other hand, you could write your processes and controls to allow for not having background checks for consultants or letting people use third-party email addresses. You may need additional controls or processes to protect data.

In my experience in organizations that have undergone security audits (like SOC2, ISO 27001, and similar), they tend to have the same processes for employees, contractors, and consultants regarding onboarding and the use of company-managed assets (computers, email addresses) for work. It makes the processes a bit more streamlined and can give confidence in the security of the company's information. There are probably alternatives, though, but I'm not sure what those are simply because the organizations have opted for what is (to me, anyway) the more straightforward approach.

Comment: Thank Thomas. Unfortunately there are no standard process followed in the organization and that's where I wanted the help so that I can get the process set properly.

Comment: @Amit Then you need to define those processes well before your SOC 2 audit. The audit will check how those processes and other controls (like tool configurations and architectures) work and make sure that they are being followed. But do see my last paragraph - my experience tells me that treating employees and contractors and consultants the same (with no difference for former employees) is probably the most straightforward, but could be more costly if you pay for background checks often.